# EF6 transaction.Complete() fails giving "The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION"

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, asp.net-mvc-5

I inherited a small piece of ASP.NET C# code which uses EF6 BulkInsert() to add a number of records (typically 1 to 1000 rows) to a SQL Server table (with only a few fields). It runs a lot and is usually successful. **Occasionally** it fails, apparently at the transaction.Complete() call - after having **successfully** inserted records.

```
var _TransactionOption = new TransactionOptions
{
    IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.Serializable,
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TRANSACTION_MAXSECONDS)
};

using (var _Trans = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, _TransactionOption))
{
    _db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = UseAutoDetectChangesEnabled_;
    var options = new BulkInsertOptions
    {
        EnableStreaming = true,
        TimeOut = 120,
        SqlBulkCopyOptions = SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock
    };
    _db.BulkInsert(_Data.Values, options);
    ...// DEBUG HERE IS DISPLAYED WHEN THERE'S AN EXCEPTION...
    _Trans.Complete(); // THIS GENERATES THE EXCEPTION
} catch ... { ERROR REPORTED HERE }
```

It fails with "*The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION*".

I don't understand what is failing. Why is Complete() generating a ROLLBACK error and why didn't that happen on the BulkInsert? The table into which values are being inserted has no unique indexes or other constraints that would generate an exception.

Also perplexing for me is that exceptions are appearing in PROD but they not in QA, for the same data, which suggests some part of the entity framework implementation is not set up the same, but I can't see what that is.

The code is using multiple threads to do these inserts and I suspect that may be contributing.

So the question is - *why is this failing?* In the absence of an answer (and it seems likely that no-one would know) the follow-up question is - *what logging can I add to discover the cause?*

This is all on Windows Server 2019.

--Other things I tried--
I've added logging to list the values in _Data to see if there's anything in there that would generate errors at the database end. I added validation to ensure the string being inserted is no larger than the field into which it's being inserted and the couple other fields are valid for their targets. I looked to see if installations of .NET were the same on PROD and QA: These servers appear to be configured quite differently, but the components in **Server Manager->Local Server->Roles and Features->Web Server (IIS)->Web Server->Application Development** seem the same on both.

Logging revealed nothing about the cause of the exception.

I looked through the other SO entries which discuss this error and they don't address the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multithreading in combination with the `Serializable` isolation and Table Lock option is likely causing your issue.  I recommend removing the multi-threading and see if that fixes your issue.  Use some queuing mechanism if it is from multiple sources (e.g.: multiple user sessions).  Also, have you ruled out whether either `Timeout` property is being hit?

The `Serializable` isolation level is the most strict option and most prone to blocking and deadlocks.  The table lock option will also limit concurrency.  Are there any readers of this table while the load is occurring?  You may want to change the `Serializable` isolation level to `Read Committed` (much more forgiving on concurrency; default for SQL Server) and remove the `TableLock` from the options.  These settings are good for performance with very large bulk inserts.  Your typical data volume up to 1K records is not going to have any meaningful benefit using those settings.

Comment: That's helpful @CElliott. Thanks. The nature of this application is to process callbacks that are asynchronous by nature. One may come in while another is being processed. It would be a substantial effort to rearchitect the application to queue incoming requests, though I can see that would help. Before doing that I will check the isolation level to "Read Committed" as you suggest. Also, yes, it's unlikely but true that a user may read from the table while it's being loaded. It won't be a problem for that user if the results are not accurate in that moment so TableLock can go too.